# How can I set a foreign key constraint pointing a table in a different schema?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I'm relatively new to MySQL syntax. I'm trying to set up a database with different schemas. For convenience I structured my code in two parts:

- in the first part I'm creating the tables in each schema without imposing foreign key constraints
- in the second part I'm writing ALTER TABLE commands to create foreign key relations.

When it comes to create a foreign key constraint for an ID in a table that point to a table in another schema I get

"Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table 'schema_a.table_a".

Practically, I've done this:

```
#First part
CREATE SCHEMA `schema_a`
USE `schema_a`;
CREATE TABLE `table_a`
(
    IDa INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(`IDa`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB, CHARSET=..., Collate=...;


CREATE SCHEMA `schema_b`
USE `schema_b`;
CREATE TABLE `table_b`
(
    IDb INTEGER NOT NULL,
    IDa INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(`IDb`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB, CHARSET=..., Collate=...;

#Second part
USE `Schema_b`;
ALTER TABLE `table_b`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_IDa` FOREIGN KEY (`IDa`) REFERENCES `schema_a.table_a`(`IDa`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I'm not even sure if it is formally correct to create external foreign keys.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: There's no problem having a foreign key refer to another database on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` `schema_a.table_a` `` means **one** identifier, i.e. MySQL assumes that only the table name is `schema_a.table_a`. You need to quote each part of a multi part identifier individually like in `` `schema_a`.`table_a` ``.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_b`
            ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_IDa`
                           FOREIGN KEY (`IDa`)
                                       REFERENCES `schema_a`.`table_a`
                                                  (`IDa`)
                                       ON DELETE CASCADE
                                       ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Or you can just not quote in your particular case.